# How to create a unique column in SQL Azure Federation

Tags: azure-sql-database

I need to create two columns in a federated table where `ID` is a primary key and `EMAIL_ADDRESS` can never contain duplicate values. Think of it like a user being able to register only one email address at a time, and each user has a unique `ID`.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PERSON
(
    ID uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
    , EMAIL_ADDRESS nvarchar(256) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_C1] UNIQUE CLUSTERED
    (
    ID ASC,
    EMAIL_ADDRESS ASC
    )
) FEDERATED ON ([dist] = ID);
GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_email_address 
    ON PERSON(ID, EMAIL_ADDRESS);
GO
```

This will allow me to create a table, but I can still save duplicate values under `EMAIL_ADDRESS`.

How can I prevent duplicate email address entries?

Answer (score 2):

You can only have uniqueness validation within a single federation, same as partitioned table allow for aligned uniqueness validation only within a partition (federations don't have an 'unaligned' equivalent). The solution is trivial: create a separate, non-federated,  Azure DB used only to validate email uniqueness.

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the purpose of using federated databases though? Using a non-federated table should not allow me to scale out that specific table.

Comment: Sure you can scale it. If you have that many subscribers as to fill 150Gb of email addresses, simply create a different federation partitioned by email. Or by email hash. That will allow you to scale as much as you like *and* have uniqueness enforced.